# How do I get updated row id in ZEND?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I use

```
$table->update($data, $where);
```

How do I get updated row id in ZEND?

Answer (score 1):

As with working with just the plain ol' SQL, just re-query for the info you want. Use `$table->select('rowid')->where($where)` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

from [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update) :

> The return value is the **number of
>   rows affected** by the update
>   operation.

its not what you want. so you need to using select to get the row